# How to perform bitwise OR of two hexadecimal numbers using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have written the following line in a batch script

```
set KEYWORD = 0x4000|0x200
```

and when I run it, it says

> 0x200 is not recognized as internal or external command

Please help me to do a bitwise OR of two hexadecimal numbers using a batch script.

Comment: You're also going to want to use `set /a` for doing math.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of how to:

```
set /a "KEYWORD = 0x4000 | 0x200"
set /a "KEYWORD = 0x4000 ^ 0x200"
set /a "KEYWORD = 0x4000 & 0x200"
```

The double quotes are important, else it will be seen as `cmd.exe` operators and not as part of the `set /a` command.